# Preloading Web Speech API before calling speak

Tags: javascript, speech, speech-synthesis, synthesize, webspeech-api

So I've noticed that after you do the first speak using `speechSynthesis.speak`, it speeds up dramatically in providing results. So my aim below was to speed it up by pre-initializing the synthesis so when we call `speakIt()` we don't have to wait for it. It hasn't sped up at all; any suggestions on why it's not speeding up and how I fix it?

**Full Script:**

```
var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("test");
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
speech.default = false;
speech.voice = voices.filter(function(voice) { return voice.name == 'Google  UK English Male'; })[0];
speech.lang = 'en-GB';

function speakIt(word){
        speech.text = word;
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
}
```

`chrome.tts.speak` seems to be a bit quicker but certainly isn't there, but that's not the point — this should still work. Until someone finds the answer I will migrate to Chrome's usage.

Comment: This might be very unsavory, but have you tried calling `speakIt(' .')` to prime the pump a little more?

Comment: I also tried this method! It doesn't seem to fix it, it seems like the speech utterance kind of expires after a while until you speak again.. The other problem is with speechsynthesisutterance ("") makes a sound like the guy on the other end has suddenly come down with something! I tried doing that and then cancel as well, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some setup before performing speech.  I wish more examples included this.  Specifically you should call getVoices() *and* add an event handler to populate voices ahead of time when the page loads.  I've written a class that does this for you.  See the Codepen example.

```
var speech = new Speech();

if (speech.supported()) {
  speech.speak('hello, speech is working fine');
}
```

Codepen Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNwOAO